# C++11 function template specializes as a class method if it exists

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have this function template:

```
template <class T>
Json::Value write_json(const T& object);
```

When *T* is an *int*, the specialization is simple:

```
template <>
Json::Value write_json(const int& object) {
  Json::Value output;
  output = object;
  return output;
};
```

However, for more complex classes, I want it to call a method if it exists:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_write_json_method {
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U>().write_json(), bool()) test(int) { return true; };

    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }

    static constexpr bool value = test<T>(int());
};

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<has_write_json_method<T>::value, Json::Value>::type write_json(const T& object)  {
    object.write_json();
};
```

For instance, for class *foo*:

```
Json::Value foo::write_json(void) { 
  Json::Value output;
  output = 42;
  return output;
};
```

I want to call every class like:

```
int x_int;
write_json(x_int);
foo x_foo;
write_json(x_foo);
```

However, I got:

```
error: call of overloaded 'write_json(const foo&)' is ambiguous
```

How can I remove this ambiguity?

Comment: You do not show the code that makes the call.

Comment: @keith I think that it is clearer now what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it in simpler manner:

```
template<class T>
struct json_helper {   
    static void write_json(const T& t) {
        return t.write_json();
    }
};

template<class T>
void write_json(const T& t) {
    return json_helper<T>::write_json(t);
}


template<>
struct json_helper<int>{
    static void write_json(const int &i) {
    }
};

struct foo {
    void write_json(void) const { }
};
struct bar {};

int main() {
    foo f;
    write_json(f);
    // write_json(bar{}); << this won't work
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/neGtXq)

Comment: I like your (KISS) solution. But I don't find the way to deal with std::vector<T>

Comment: @Medicalphysicist it is pretty simple, add another explicit istantiation of struct json_helper: template<class T> struct json_helper<std::vector<T>>{...} ;. That is all

Comment: I have memory problems (munmap_chunk error) with this solution when write_json returns a class I defined instead of void. Do you know why?

Comment: @Medicalphysicist this seems like not an issue with this solution, just a hint that you have error somewhere else. munmap_chunk error happens when you invalidly call free/delete so I'd start search with copy/move constructors and destructors

Answer (score 3):

You should apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) on another overload too, to avoid ambiguity when the type `T` has the method `write_json`.

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_write_json_method<T>::value, void>::type write_json(const T& object);
//                      ^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H6abA9m3D3Tdtauz)

Answer (score 1):

You could do tag dispatching:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void write_json_impl(const T& object, std::true_type)  {
    object.write_json();
};

template <class T>
void write_json_impl(const T& object, std::false_type)  {
};

template <typename T>
struct has_write_json_method {
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr decltype(std::declval<U>().write_json(), bool()) test(int) { return true; };

    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }

    static constexpr bool value = test<T>(int());

    // Add this:
    using type = typename std::conditional<value, std::true_type, std::false_type>::type;
    // or this:
    // using type = std::integral_constant<bool, value>;
};

template <class T>
void write_json(const T& object)
{
    return write_json_impl(object, typename has_write_json_method<T>::type{});
};

struct Foo { void write_json() const {} };

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    write_json(f);
    write_json(0);
}
```

[Live.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ecf3e0fb6b7aad0)